# Effecient way for finding values of one dataframe in another

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (RES1):

```
    "sequence" "support"
"1" "<{OV50}>"   0.286
"2" "<{OV148}>"  0.121
```

And additional dataframe (SRC2):

```
  "sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV56"
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV148"
```

I would like to get the following output dataframe (OUT3):

```
  "sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" "Co"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"     1
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"     0
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"    1       0.67
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV56"     0
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV148"    1       0.5
```

For Each row in SRC2 the "Exist" column in OUT3 will be '0' if there is no value at all in RES1. For instance, OV11 doesn't appear in RES1 at all so its value is 0.
At the last value of sequenceID - the amount of '1' values is divided by the number of the same sequenceID and is added to "Co" column. In line 3 the there were 3 lines of sequenceID = 42207993 number of '1' are 2 so 2/3 = 0.67.
I would like to find the most efficient way to do it because each of the dataframes is very big dataframe.

Comment: Are the `data.frames` or `matrices`?  `data.frame` cannot have duplicate row names

Comment: Hi @akrun, you can relate them as matrices and afterwards I'll do the transformation if it helps. Some of them are dataframes while others are txt files.

Comment: Hi @akrun, the row name was fixed. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I get an error: > setDT(SRC2)[, Exist := +(items %chin% gsub('[^[:alnum:]]+', '', RES1$sequence))]
Error in items %chin% gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+", "", RES1$sequence) : 
  x is type 'integer' (must be 'character' or NULL)

Comment: I am guessing that you have factor column 'items'.  Can you convert it to `character` before doing the operation.  Also, please test with the data I showed in the post.

Comment: Your solution is perfect, How can I transform the 'items' (which are column in dataframe) into character?

Comment: Just do `SRC2$items <- as.character(SRC2$items)` before we do the `setDT`

Comment: It is not clear.  What if `OV195` occurs after `OV197`?  I think a new question with this and expected output makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to `data.table` (`setDT(SRC2)`), remove the punctuation characters in 'sequence' column of 'RES1' using `gsub`, check whether it is present in the 'items', coerce the logical vector to binary by wrapping with `+` and assign (`:=`) the output to a new column 'Exist'.  Grouped by 'sequenceID', we divided the `sum` of 'Exist' by the nrow  (`.N`), `round`, convert to 'character' and assign it as 'Co'.  Then, we get the row index (`.I`) of those elements that are not the last row per each 'sequenceID' and assign those to `''`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(SRC2)[, Exist := +(items %chin% gsub('[^[:alnum:]]+', 
           '', RES1$sequence))]
i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , 
            sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$V1
SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
SRC2
#   sequenceID transactionID eventID items Exist   Co
#1:   42207993          1577       1  OV50     1     
#2:   42207993          6048       2  OV11     0     
#3:   42207993          1597       3 OV148     1 0.67
#4:   57237976         12423       1  OV56     0     
#5:   57237976         12589       2 OV148     1  0.5
```

#### data

```
SRC2 <- structure(list(sequenceID = c(42207993L, 42207993L, 
 42207993L, 
 57237976L, 57237976L), transactionID = c(1577L, 6048L, 1597L, 
 12423L, 12589L), eventID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L),
 items = c("OV50", 
 "OV11", "OV148", "OV56", "OV148")), .Names = c("sequenceID", 
 "transactionID", "eventID", "items"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

RES1 <- structure(list(sequence = c("<{OV50}>", "<{OV148}>"),
 support = c(0.286,    
 0.121)), .Names = c("sequence", "support"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked perfect (I did it simultaneously before your previous comment. I added another issue in the end of question body.

Comment: @Avi I didn't find any updates in your question body

Comment: @Avi Can you post that as separate question as it involves some splitting.